# How do WF4 parse the Expressions?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, reflector

How do WF4 parse expressions and return the values.

for example the If activity has the Condition attribute that we can write expression like [ true = true ] or [ "str" = "str" ] or guids...
what is the class responsible for this parsing?

I noticed that when we put the [] so the engine will directly parse the content of the brackets, in other world what is the class that parses the VB expression in WF4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you are looking for is [VisualBasicValue< TResult>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782058.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Maurice, it's exactly what i want :) Is this the best approach to do by own expression and parse it?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. In the end this is a workflow activity so it needs to work within the context of the workflow runtime. Now even if you are doing something else that isn't a big requirement as WorklfowInvoker is quite easy and light to use.